# C# dictionary with property gives error in C#?

Tags: c#, properties, dictionary

I have a dictionary which contains a struct as key, I have to create a property for the dictionary

**project1**

```
namespace ClassLibrary2
{
  public class Class1
  {
    public Dictionary<string, Cs> mdic;
    public Class1()
    {
        mdic = new Dictionary<string, Cs>();
        mdic.Add("Welcome", new Cs() { m1 = "12",m2="32"});
    }

    public Dictionary<string, Cs> Dic
    {
        get {return mdic;}
        set { value = mdic; }
    }

    public struct Cs
    {
        public string m1{get;set;}
        public string m2{get;set;}
    }
}
```

When I try to set this value on `project 1` it shows error...

Like this I set

**project2**

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication20
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
     public Form1()
     {
        InitializeComponent();
     }

     private Dictionary<string, Cs> Dic
     {
        get;
        set;
     }

     struct Cs
     {
         public string m1 { get; set; }
         public string m2 { get; set; }
     }

     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        ClassLibrary2.Class1 css = new ClassLibrary2.Class1();
        Dic = css.Dic;
     }
 }
```

I am having problem in  `css.Dic` `..... System Generic Collections`

Comment: Looks like your dictionary has strings for keys, not your struct

Comment: First of all - it's **C#** - not "csharp" or "c-sharp" or "c sharp" or anything like that.... secondly: **WHAT** error do you get? Please put the **full** and **complete** error - and thirdly - haven't you asked this question (at least once) before??

Answer (score 2):

The ClassLibrary2.Class1.Cs struct and the WindowsFormsApplication20.Form1.Cs struct are 2 different types and therefore you cannot assign a `Dictionary<string, ClassLibrary2.Class1.Cs>` to a variable of type `Dictionary<string, WindowsFormsApplication20.Form1.Cs>`. Try instead to remove the Cs declaration from your Form1 as in the following:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private Dictionary<string, ClassLibrary2.Class1.Cs> Dic
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClassLibrary2.Class1 css = new ClassLibrary2.Class1();
        Dic = css.Dic;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionary definition in Form1 should be -

```
private Dictionary<string, ClassLibrary2.Class1.Cs> Dic
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have allready recieved answer in your privious question comments.

Your `ClassLibrary2.Class1.CS` and `WindowsFormsApplication20.Form1.CS` are different structs.

in WindowsFormsApplication20 you should not declare new CS struct. just use ClassLibrary2 namespasce.

```
using ClassLibrary2;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication20
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
     public Form1()
     {
        InitializeComponent();
     }

     private Dictionary<string, Class1.Cs> Dic
     {
        get;
        set;
     }

     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        ClassLibrary2.Class1 css = new ClassLibrary2.Class1();
        Dic = css.Dic;
     }
 }
```